# Не изменяется цвет текста

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/UNm4M/

HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
    <div id="footer">
    <div id="info">
        <p>(812) 316-3866, 575-0717, 316-7855, 575-0720</p>
        <p><i>fff</i>190005, Санкт-Петербург, ул. 4-я Красноармейская, д. 3, оф. 22</p>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#footer {
    margin-top:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 98px;
    background:#054d6a;
}
#info {
    outline:1px solid black;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:970px;
    font-family: PFDinTextCondpro-medium;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
}
#info p:last-child {
    font-family: PFDinTextCondpro-regular;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top:25px;
};
#info p > i{
    color:#000;
}
```

Цвет внутри тега I не хочет меняться. Но когда задаешь стили внутри самого тега, все работает. Из-за чего может такое быть?

Comment:  1. Из-за специфичности
 2. Ошибаетесь в самом css.

Уточните какой тег, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я указал не верную ссылку. Посмотрите еще раз пожалуйста

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точку с запятой уберите в стилях. http://jsfiddle.net/UNm4M/1/

Comment: Все верно. Как и было сказано, ошибка в css.